# In Tap Counter App display different images when certain count is reached

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.5

I am creating a simple tap counter app.  The UI consists of a button - which is pressed for counting, a label which shows the count and an image view.
I want to be able to change the image when the count reaches a certain amount.  For example if the count is between 0 and 100 I want to see image1, then when the count is between 101 an 200 I want to see image2.

Here is my code so far:

h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int counter;

@interface tapcount : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UILabel *count;
    IBOutlet UIImage *imageview;
}

-(IBAction)click;
```

m file:

```
@implementation tapcount

-(IBAction)click {
    counter=counter +1;
    count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
    if (counter > 0) counter = 0;
    if (counter > 100);
}
```

I don't know how to call the Image view.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

in .h file

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    int counter;

    @interface tapcount : UIViewController {

            IBOutlet UILabel *count;
            IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;
        }

    -(IBAction)click;
```

in click method set image...

```
    -(IBAction)click 
    {
            counter=counter +1;
            count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
            if (counter >= 0 && counter <= 100)  {
                    imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
            }
            else if (counter >= 101 && counter <= 200) {
                    imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
            }
            else if (counter >= 201 && counter <= 300) {
                    imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
            }
            ....
    }
```

and most important: take uiimageview in .xib file.

Comment: Thankyou, unfortunately that hasn't worked, I get the error: 'Property image not found on object of type UIImageview'

Comment: take uiimageview insted of uiimage

Comment: any ideas on how to set a maximum count?

Comment: suppose your maximum count is 1000. then check in your click method  if(counter >= 1000) {   counter = 0; // or do any action  }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27565/discussion-between-mustafa-and-dharaparekh)

Answer (score 1):

just have the `click` method like below

```
- (IBAction) click {
counter++;
count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",counter];
if (counter > 0 && counter < 101)
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageNamecount100.png"];
else if (counter > 100 && counter < 201)
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageNamecount200.png"];
else
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageNamedefault.png"];
}
```

Comment: any ideas on how to set a maximum count?